# Detect when NSTabview reloads in Swift

Tags: swift, tableview, nstableview

I am trying to add a label to the window whenever the tableview item count is zero. I figured that the best way to do this would be to check `tableView.numberOfRows` after tableview reloads . However, I can't seem to find a way to detect it when the tableview reloads. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Better display a label when the data count is zero. When do you tell the the table view to reload?

Comment: When adding or removing a row. Also when filtering the tableview data array.

Comment: That's when you check.

Comment: There are many instances of that ,so detecting reload and checking row count would be easier. However, that doesn't seem to be possible. So I checked for row count after every reload.

Answer (score 2):

Table views don't spontaneously reload. You tell them when to reload. You should probably have a central data model object, and have it notify your view controller when the items count reaches zero. (You could set up your data model object to have a delegate, for example, and give the delegate a `itemCountChanged(to:)` method.)

Comment: tableview delegate method ```numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView)```  runs every time the tableview reloads but I don't think it is safe to run other code inside this method. I am looking for something similar.

Comment: I assume you mean the table view data source method. (`numberOfRows(in:)` is a method in the `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol.)

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Would it be safe to hide/unhide a Label from there?